# Calling Rest WCF Service under RP in WP8 applications

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, rest, windows-phone-8

I'm trying to call a REST webservice who is under a Reverse Proxy.
I'm sure that login, domain and password are correct.

I use the HTTPClient portable lib.

```
private async void bt1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var c = new NetworkCredential()
        {
            Domain = "XXXXX",
            UserName = "XXXX.XXXX",
            Password = "XXXXXXX"
        };

        HttpClientHandler h = new HttpClientHandler();
        h.Credentials = c;

        HttpClient cl = new HttpClient(h);

        HttpResponseMessage response = await cl.GetAsync("https://XXXXXXXXX.fr/XXXXXXX.svc/getdepartcollection");

    }
```

Maybe i make a misstake, or maybe there is another way to call service. I have this result :

> {StatusCode: 401, ReasonPhrase: 'Authorization Required', Version: 0.0, Content: System.Net.Http.StreamContent, Headers:
>   {
>     Date: Tue, 01 Jul 2014 09:30:03 GMT
>     WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="XXXXXX"
>     Set-Cookie: BWFSESSID_mhcqaf7yddn5kzq7jjef72v5h2=xehlsv8hlmpbh75z3u897ug6m20uchyl5b7masyu77aqd5n95c3xrpx6ph27nlc2bs5gmfyqhrzhs882bkwvfcq49m79axrasgpcv9lxum6nqarm55sxtrm9pwsw6wladd82fe8v3rv2bcufcc6jfhg9fnjfpf9t43rxlsbhgwq4ba93zp69745hnzwzcxx8nnem67l8jdqanx223q7bvhwp49ramv6b8xl6yuspd5heduwsturxvnlrqekvrjuycs; Path=/; Secure; httpOnly
>     Cache-Control: max-age=0, private
>     Pragma: no-cache
>     Vary: Accept-Encoding
>     Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=299
>     Connection: Keep-Alive
>     Content-Length: 401
>     Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
>   }}

EDIT : I follow this link but it doesnt work too : http://pranayamr.blogspot.in/2011/06/calling-cross-domain-wcf-service-using.html

here is my web.config :

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>

  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <standardEndpoints>
      <webScriptEndpoint>
        <standardEndpoint crossDomainScriptAccessEnabled="true"/>
      </webScriptEndpoint>
    </standardEndpoints>
    <services>
      <service name="XXXXXXXXXXXXXX.XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehavior">
        <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" behaviorConfiguration="web"
                  contract="XXXXXXXXXXX.XXXXXXXXXXXXXX"/>
      </service>
    </services>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="CopySoap" closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00"
          receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00" allowCookies="false"
          bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
          maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxBufferSize="655360" maxReceivedMessageSize="655360"
          textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered" useDefaultWebProxy="true"
          messageEncoding="Text">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
            maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
          <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
            <transport clientCredentialType="Ntlm" proxyCredentialType="Ntlm"
              realm="" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="http://XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.fr/_vti_bin/copy.asmx"
        binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="CopySoap"
        contract="SP.CopySoap" name="CopySoap" />
    </client>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="ServiceBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="web">
          <webHttp/>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
 <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
  </system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

Comment: are you sure Crossdomain policy is implemeted in yourr WCF Rest service?

Comment: I created a clientaccessprolicy and a crossdomain but it didnt change anything.

Comment: http://pranayamr.blogspot.in/2011/06/calling-cross-domain-wcf-service-using.html